# Use a SQL Server Table-valued function like a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have built a table-valued function in SQL Server 2012 that returns the last known location for each unique vehicle in a table before a user-defined date and time:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LAST_AVL_LOC] (@dateIn datetime2(7))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT p.title, 
           p.local_Time,
           p.vgroup,
           p.speed,
           p.heading,
           p.latitude, 
           p.longitude,
           p.shape,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.title ORDER BY p.local_Time desc) AS rk
           FROM ac.AVL_POINTS p where  p.local_Time < @dateIn)
SELECT s.*
  FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk = 1
```

This code works well, and can be called within SQL like this:

```
select * from [dbo].[LAST_AVL_LOC]('09/05/2016')
```

This will return a table of each unique vehicle in the table with its last known location and other information before 09/05/2016.

My problem is this function needs to be used by a GIS package outside of SQL, and the only SQL constructs exposed and "callable" to the this software are tables and views. I would like to wrap this table-valued function in a view so it could be called in a manner such as this and still return the same table:

```
select * from VIEW_LAST_AVL_LOC where last_date = '09/05/2016'
```

Is such a feat possible?

Comment: A view is just that...a view. It cannot receive parameters.

Comment: Could you rewrite this function to do something like GROUP BY p.local_Time?
you are using where query by date, i don't think that it will be huge result set. 
Also another idea - MSSQL2012 can create Memory Optimizaed Tables, you can preloading your data to this table

Comment: Write a view that is mostly the same but without `p.local_Time < @dateIn`, and call it using `select * from view where local_time < '09/05/2016'`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely achievable.

We implemented a similar denormalised set of functions for the Data Vault for the contract I work on.

If we wanted to view record states for a particular date we just pass the date eg: (2015/05/01) and it returns all records and their states at that time.

For data vault based systems i would strongly recommend this sort of method.

**Example of how we have set up our denormilised functions**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Customer_Contacts_AsAt] (@date datetime(7))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    SELECT 
        h.hk_Customer_Contact
        h.Number
        s.CustomerID
        s.CustomerName
        s.Job_ID
        s.Title
        s.Description
        s.Loaction
        s.Submit_Date
        s.Fulfill_Date
    FROM
            dvr.hub_Customer_Contacts h
    join    dvr.sat_Customer_Contacts s     on h.hk_Customer_Contact = s.hk_Customer_Contact
    WHERE
        s.Load_Date > @date
    and s.Load_EndDate < @date
```

Answer (score 0):

Create VIEW without where condition (**where  p.local_Time < @dateIn**). So it will have all the data and you can use the following query:

select * from VIEW_LAST_AVL_LOC where last_date = '09/05/2016'

Note: We cannot use parameters with Views.

Comment: Removing the where clause and turning this into a view has incorrect behavior.  The function returned the last location before a date.  If you input '2016-09-13 15:00' you would get the last location for each unique car before that time, whether it was two minutes or two days before.

With the view, entering where last_date = '2016-09-13 15:00' doesn't work, since it only returns locations at that exact time.  Entering last_date < '2016-09-13 15:00' returns all unique cars that reported before that time, but not after.  If a car reported the next day, it will be excluded from the result.